# The connection was reset - Wordpress Permalinks

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I migrate a Wordpress webpage from one hosting to a DigitalOcean Ubuntu 14.04 droplet using [All-in-One WP Migration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/) and now I have problems with Permalinks.

Home page, pages and admin panel are working but if I want to go in a Post all of them show this:
[Firefox error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKp0k.png)

I activate mod_rewrite, check on .htaccess Wordpress rules, I test all permalinks configurations and also check /var/log/apache2/error.log

**Apache VirtualHost configuration**

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin myemail@my-domain.com
     ServerName my-domain.com
     ServerAlias www.my-domain.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/my-domain/my-domain.com

     <Directory /var/www/my-domain/my-domain.com>
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
     </Directory>

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**.htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

**/var/log/apache2/error.log**

```
[Sun Oct 18 08:37:06.217695 2015] [core:notice] [pid 20185] AH00051: child pid 29727 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! 
The error is caused by the theme of the web page I have to reinstall it and everything go back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was weird.

i got error when i run the url

http://mysite.org.in/wp-admin/

> The connection was reset
>
> The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

then i tried

https://mysite.org.in/wp-admin/

and it start working.
i don't know how it happened but it's working now.